# Github Actions - Updating an HTML File

Tags: javascript, github, yaml, github-actions

I have a static website that I am deploying with Github Actions. The website consists of 1 HTML file and several .yaml config files. There is a simple javascript function that loads all the .yaml files. However, currently the list of .yaml files is hardcoded. Is there anyway to either:

1. Use Github Actions to update the javascript array before deploying the website?
2. Use javascript to dynamically create the list based on the files in the config directory?

**Directory structure**

```sh
index.html
config/
|-- first.yaml
|-- second.yaml
|-- ...
```

**index.html**

```html
...
<script>
// how can we dynamically create this array?
var files = [
  {"name": "first.yaml"},
  {"name": "second.yaml"},
  ...
]
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps do an `ls config` and pipe that into a `sed` command that replaces the files in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
bluwy/substitute-string-action@v1

Here is an example:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: bluwy/substitute-string-action@v1
      id: sub
      with:
        _input-text: 'Hello World!'
        World: GitHub
```

Url to the action with the full docs:
https://github.com/bluwy/substitute-string-action

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wWvp.jpg

Comment: Hi - can you please provide an example with the structure in my question? I am having difficulty understanding how this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put together solution from previous answer so you can imagine it better.

The workflow first go through `yaml` files in config directory and prints them as a string of: `"config1.yaml", "config2.yaml"`

Then uses mentioned **bluwy/substitute-string-action@v1** action to replace it in index.html file.

It is a raw solution just to showcase how you can approach this issue. Real life solution should be more complex.

You can checkout "Run cat index.html" step in my [test action](https://github.com/OndrejTuma/ga-ci/runs/5744882908?check_suite_focus=true)

index.html

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var files = [%%files%%]
</script>
```

Workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  get_config:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get files from config folder
        id: dir
        run: echo "::set-output name=files::$(ls -m config | sed -r 's/([a-z0-9]+\.ya?ml)/"\1"/gi')"

      - name: Replace file in index.html
        uses: bluwy/substitute-string-action@v1
        with:
          _input-file: 'index.html'
          _output-file: 'index.html'
          _format-key: '%%key%%'
          files: ${{ steps.dir.outputs.files }}
```